# Basic Java environment question:

Tags: java

CLASSPATH
PATH

Which goes into User and which goes into System?  I get different answers from different sites.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand. I didn't know there was a setting. I ask so that I can be answered; I thought it was the whole point.

Comment: correct ... but to get more answers you should accept answers to your earlier questions ... so that people will get attracted :)

Comment: When you accept an answer you tell future searchers that the answer is correct/viable/useful for the question.

Answer (score 2):

**CLASSPATH** : An environment variable which specifies the directories to search for classes.

e.g: When I build a J2EE application, i would need `servlet-api.jar`, as this is not provided by the standard Java Library, you need to tell the compiler (javac in my case).

I can do this by either:

```
javac -classpath "some-path" my_program.java
```

or

```
CLASSPATH="some-path"
javac  my_program.java
```

or

```
mv some-path/library.jar /usr/lib/jvm/java-(version)-sun/lib
javac my_program.java
```

The thid option would work only if you are a system administrator.
If you need to make your changes permanent, export CLASSPATH in your bashrc (or some other way in windows)

Note: that when you import a jar file from an IDE (eclipse/netbeans), it does most of the hardwork for you.You only need to do all this if you are running your application from command line.

**PATH**: environment variable that specifies a path to look for executables.
So `javac` in previous case is accessible only if the location of binary is in the PATH environment variable.

Comment: Are you giving answer to the actual question ... or just pasting some academic stuff out here.

Comment: Is it academic stuff and is it really pasting :P.. I would be glad if you could quote the source.
IMHO, the best way to figure out something is to know what exactly it is. Rest the answer was helpful, and that is this whole thing all about.(The upvotes explain that)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really matter. The "System" versus "User" difference only changes who gets the variables; all users, or only you.

Comment: Which do you have yours set on?

Comment: Neither. My distro doesn't need them to find its Java stuff since it uses `alternatives` for that.

Answer (score 1):

Classpath goes into System ... I don't know which PATH are you talking about? but you should check [this](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html)

PATH => System PATH? then that also belongs to system... but that's not java specific.

Ohh! am I getting the question right?

Answer (score 1):

All environment variables have system-wide defaults (if you included "not defined" as a default value), and the system-wide default can be configured by the system administrator. Individual users can override the default for their own user accounts. For most systems, the system-wide defaults are given in `/etc/profile`, `/etc/bashrc`, or some other configuration file in the `/etc` directory. The user can override environment variables in `~/.login`, `~/.bashrc`, `~/.cshrc`, or some other hidden file (which doesn't have to exist) in their home folder, depending on which shell is their default and based on whether they would like the environment to be setup for the whole login session or for their terminal session.